# Spring-Data-Rest exposing RepositoryRestResource fails randomly when two Repository-Interfaces exist for the same domain-type

Tags: spring, spring-data-rest

Hello stack overflow

I am creating a demo application for myself using spring-data-jpa and spring-data-rest. I have two repository interfaces:

```
interface PersonRepository : PagingAndSortingRepository<Person, Long>

@RepositoryRestResource(path = "people", collectionResourceRel = "people", exported = true)
interface PeopleRepository : PagingAndSortingRepository<Person, Long>
```

I changed the repositoryDetectionStrategy to RepositoryDetectionStrategies.ANNOTATED.

I created for the personRepository a self-made RestController for the peopleRepository I want it to be created by spring and exposed at localhost:8080/   by hateos

**Problem**

- Just randomly the peopleRepository is exposed(not working at all).

After debugging I can say for sure that RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration's Bean Repositories is the reason for the problem.

org.springframework.data.repository.support.Repositories's method populateRepositoryFactoryInformation gets over all Repositories since I have two for the same Class the inner map.put overrides my desired behavior depending which bean comes first.

So is this a bug or spring does not support several Repository-Interfaces with spring-data-rest or did I misconfigure my setup?

Comment: Did you find any solution about this? I have the same problem ...

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, it seems that `SpringData` does not handle well this kind of scenario (I was using **spring-boot 1.5.8**, when I found the same problem as you... I tried to upgrade my spring version to see if this was fixed, but I begin to get other compilation/deployments issues. so I quit that idea...)

You can get more info in these links:

- [One entity Two Repositories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36112451/multiple-repositories-for-the-same-entity-in-spring-data-rest)
- [DataRest Issue/Improvement Ticket](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREST-923)