# spring boot can't find my repository after adding a new repository

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, reactive-programming, javabeans

GameRepository.java:

```
@Repository
public interface GameRepository extends MongoRepository<Game, String> {
}
```

GameRepositoryReactive.java:

```
@Repository
public interface GameRepositoryReactive extends ReactiveMongoRepository<Game, String> {
}
```

Game.java:

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Document(collection = "games")
public class Game{
    @Id
    String id;
    String name;
}
```

GameService.java:

```
private final GameRepositoryReactive gameRepositoryReactive;
    private final GameRepository gameRepository;

    public GameService(GameRepository gameRepository, GameRepositoryReactive gameRepositoryReactive) {
        this.gameRepositoryReactive = gameRepositoryReactive;
        this.gameRepository = gameRepository;
    }
```

The error I get:

> Parameter 0 of constructor in com.example.service.GameService required
> a bean of type 'com.example.repository.GameRepository' that could not
> be found.

With one ReactiveMongoRepository repository I get no error.

Comment: You either use reactive or not, you cannot mix both as Spring Boot will only auto-configure one of them. If you want both you have to manually configure them.

Comment: @M.Deinum Can I use pagination in the Reactive repository?

Comment: You can't have two repositories for the same entity. See this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58292062/spring-two-repositories-of-same-entity#:~:text=It%20is%20not%20possible%20to,Person%20class)%20using%20a%20map.

Comment: No, but you can quite easily use a flux to skip x elements and take y to simulate paging.